# How to save changes from a learnr tutorial for grading?

Tags: r, package, rstudio, learnr

I have just got started with making tutorials in learnr package.

I have used the template for the demo tutorial:

When I go on "Run Document", this allows me to write in the RStudio window that opens all the answers I have for the questions. However, I do not know how it is possible for me to save the code that I wrote in that window that opens to the .Rmd file. I do not want to use the "Publish" option either.

The idea would be that I can send the Rmd file to another person. They can "Run Document", then complete in the corresponding boxes the script and the code, then use some sort of "save" function, which would create another Rmd with all the code saved or overwrite the Rmd that I sent with the code that they wrote for those exercises. Then, if I myself run the Rmd file, I can again see all their answers together with my questions.

Would that be possible?

Comment: `learnr` does not have this functionality. The [gradethis](https://github.com/rstudio-education/gradethis) package is under active development, and you could potentially write out the answers, but the functionality you are describing would require significant development.